# Is it possible to switch/control/predicate a member function call using a ternary?

Tags: c++

The style of this is certainly questionable, but I'm curious if there is a "clean" way in C++ to do a refactor like the following.

Suppose we start with the working code:

```
if (shapeA.intersects(shapeB)) {
  // ... lots of code
} else {
  // lots more
}
```

And I want to do a quick and dirty comparison with my new intersection routine, I'd like to inject a ternary into this `if` conditional:

```
if (shapeA.(enable_opt ? intersects_optimized : intersects)(shapeB)) { // expected unqualified-id
  // hooray, we are undisturbed
} else {
  // lots more
}
```

As opposed to the pretty awful looking

```
if (enable_opt) {
  if (shapeA.intersects_optimized(shapeB)) {
    // ... lots of code
  } else {
    // lots more
  }
} else {
  if (shapeA.intersects(shapeB)) {
    // trail of tears
  } else {
    // despair and suffering
  }
}
```

The pain/ugliness involved scales somewhat with the complexity of the conditional inside...

I've tried a few ideas and although it seems like member function pointers are possible to use, it appears impossible to specify a particular overload when obtaining the function pointer for a member variable if that function name is overloaded.

Comment: I believe you can throw a `static_cast` on a (member) function pointer to guide overload resolution. However, please just distribute the ternary: `enable_opt ? shapeA.intersects_optimized(shapeB) : shapeA.intersects(shapeB)`

Comment: Ah yes. I think in the course of typing out the question I overcomplicated my ugly example a bit. I was also hoping to not have to duplicate the arguments, but... it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

There's a possible 'halfway-house' solution using the ternary which, although still repeating *some* code, involves only one `if ... else` test:

```cpp
    if (enable_opt ? shapeA.intersects_optimized(shapeB) : shapeA.intersects(shapeB)) {
        // hooray, we are undisturbed
    } else {
        // lots more
    }
```

Not sure if you count this as 'ugly' or not, though.

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly do it by selecting between pointers-to-member-function, but it wouldn't be very pretty.

Just wrap the call:

```
bool TestShapeIntersection(const Shape& a, const Shape& b)
{
    if (enable_opt)
       return a.intersects_optimized(b);
    else
       return a.intersects(b);
}
```

Then:

```
if (TestShapeIntersection(shapeA, shapeB)) {
  // hooray, we are undisturbed
} else {
  // lots more
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write the ternary as

```
if ((shapeA.*(enable_opt ? &Shape::intersects_optimized : &Shape::intersects))(shapeB)) {
   // hooray, we are undisturbed
} else {
  // lots more
}
```

But it is not a lot prettier.

Note that

- you cannot drop the `&Shape::` part;
- you need the additional pair of parentheses;
- it is not exactly idiomatic.

The alternatives that move the call into a helper function are preferable.

Comment: you were too fast for me ;-)
Here the code, to play online with it: https://godbolt.org/z/i5F6z4